# Different Value of Lookup Field in different Views

Tags: 2007, list, development, custom, custom-list

here's the code

```
    using (SPSite site = new SPSite("https://mysite.com/Ting/default.aspx"))
    {
        using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
        {
            SPList SourceList = web.Lists["Record1"];
            SPList TargetList = web.Lists["Record2"];

            SourceList.Fields.AddLookup("Certificate", TargetList.ID, false);
            SPFieldLookup lkp = (SPFieldLookup)SourceList.Fields["Certificate"];

            lkp.LookupField = TargetList.Fields["Name"].InternalName;
            lkp.Update();

            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                SPView view = SourceList.Views[i];
                view.ViewFields.Add("Certificate");
                view.Update();
            }
        }
    }
```

what I am doing here is creating a lookup field in a already created Sharepoint list, Problem is, when I add a to Source List, it shows me all the certificates in a drop down choice, but when i see all the items view,  it shows certificate names as " 1_.000" and increment by the number of items i add to the list, even if i use same certificate.

sounds like a logical problem to me :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Reason was because, both Sharepoint builtin Forms were calling different attributes of the lookup field.

In order to finish my task, i created a event handler that, copies name field to Title field, so that later on i can use it.